# PHP: calculate a period of time in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to calculate a period of time in a `foreach` loop but I can't access the next value to do my subtraction:

```
foreach($jsonArrayDateEtat as $key=>$valeur){
 var_dump($valeur['StatusName']);
 if($Etat==$valeur['StatusName'][$key]){ //this is not working 
 echo "I am inside the if loop";
 $now   =strtotime ($valeur[$key]); //this is not working either
 $after = strtotime($valeur[$key+1]); //this is not working either
 print_r( abs($after- $now ) );

}
```

This notation is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to count the time your loop is taking to execute/

Comment: no actually am tryng to count the time between the value $now wich is the first value of the array and the value $after wich is the second value of the array by doing a substraction but in my foreach loop i can't acces to the second value of the array

Comment: you could try using a for loop. there you can use `$i+1` to access next value.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i found :

```
foreach($jsonArrayDateEtat as $key=>$valeur){
  //var_dump($valeur['StatusName']);
  if($valeurEtat==$valeur['StatusName']){
  $cptPie=1; 
   $now   =strtotime ($jsonArrayDateEtat[$key]['ChangeStatusDate']);//use the key to increment to the next value 
   $after = strtotime($jsonArrayDateEtat[$key+1]['ChangeStatusDate']);
   $duree=abs($after - $now );
  $somme=$somme+$duree;
 }
```